# How to keep the date value of calender extender after postback of other control?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

For example:

There is a calender-extender for a textbox txt1 and i choose a date value for it.
After that, there is a radio button-list with values One and two with post-back events.
When i choose One or Two, then after the post-back, the value in the txt1 gets disappeared.

Comment: you should have searched the topic first. You are asking how to persist control data during postbacks. : Here are some ways : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

Comment: Please include the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Enable ViewState= true